# Filling out a PDF/A3-Acroform with itext7 makes the PDF lose its PDF/A3 compliance and I can't figure out why

Tags: itext, itext7, pdfa

I have a PDF/A3 file with an empty acroform inside, which needs to be filled programmatically. I chose to use the itext7 library and at first everything seemed to go really well. Filling the acroform was seemingly pretty easy and the result looked good.

Now the resulting PDF file still needs to be PDF/A3 conformant, but for some reason, after filling out the form with my program, when I check against verapdf to confirm the validity of my PDF file, I get the following error:
[image: verapdf error]

I have absolutely no idea where to even start fixing this. When decoding the resulting PDF the following two sections are the only parts which contain anything with "pdfuaid":

```
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
  xmlns:pdfaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/"
  xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
  xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
  xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#"
  xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/"
  xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#"
  xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#"
  xmlns:pdfaType="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/type#"
  xmlns:pdfaField="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/field#"
  xmlns:ftx="http://ns.ftx.com/forms/1.0/"
  xmlns:control="http://ns.ftx.com/forms/1.0/controldata/"
  xmlns:pdfuaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfua/ns/id/"

  <ftx:ControlData
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Hausnummer="3"
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Namenszusatz="0"
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Postleitzahl="10"
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Titel="0"
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Vorname="4"
  control:Anzahl_Zeichen_Wohnsitzlaendercode="1"
  control:Auftragsnummer_Einsender="0"
  control:Formularnummer="10"
  control:Formularversion="07.2017"
  control:Technische_Version="3"/>
  <pdfuaid:part>1</pdfuaid:part>
```

This is the code which fills the PDF:

```
PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(new PdfReader(TEMPLATE), new PdfWriter(DEST + name + ".pdf"));

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.CP1252, true);

// Hole Acro-Form aus der PDF
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, false);

// Lese XMP-Metadaten aus der PDF
byte[] xmp = pdf.getXmpMetadata();
XMPMeta meta = XMPMetaFactory.parseFromBuffer(xmp);

JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) this.parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonFile));

// Durchlaufe JSON-Array, in dem alle zu befüllenden Felder stehen
for (Object obj : jsonArr) {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) obj;

    // Lese Daten für dieses Feld aus
    String feld = (String) json.get("Bezeichnung");
    String val = (String) json.get("value");
    String ez = (String) json.get("EZ");
    String az = (String) json.get("AZ");
    String fontSizeStr = (String) json.get("Size");

    // Setze Default FontSize auf 12pt und ändere diese, wenn anders
    // spezifiziert in JSON-Datei
    int fontSize = 12;
    if (fontSizeStr != null && !fontSizeStr.equals("")) {
        fontSize = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeStr);
    }

    if (ez.equals("meta")) {

        meta.setStructField(nsControlData, "ControlData", nsControl, feld, val);

    } else {

        // Lese Art des Feldes aus && parse maximal erlaubte Anzahl
        // von
        // Zeichen
        int maxChar = 0;
        int maxDisplay = 0;
        boolean kreuzFeld = false;
        if (!ez.equals("K")) {
            maxChar = Integer.parseInt(ez);
            maxDisplay = Integer.parseInt(az);
        } else {
            kreuzFeld = true;
        }

        // Befülle Acro-Form
        if (!kreuzFeld) {
            String value = val;
            String display = val;
            if (value.length() > maxChar) {
                value = value.substring(0, maxChar);
            }
            if (display.length() > maxDisplay) {
                display = display.substring(0, maxDisplay);
            }
            // Ersetze ";" durch "\n" im Stempel && verringere die
            // Fontsize auf 6
            if (feld.equals("0000_Vertragsarztstempel")) {
                value = value.replace(";", "\n");
                fontSize = 6;
            }

            // Setze Wert und Schriftart für dieses Feld
            try {
                // form.getField(feld).setFontSize(fontSize);
                form.getField(feld).setFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
                form.getField(feld).setValue(value, display);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(feld);
            }
        } else {
            if (!val.equals("0")) {
                form.getField(feld).setValue("Yes");
            }
        }
    }

}
// Korrigiere technische Version
meta.setStructField(nsControlData, "ControlData", nsControl, "Technische_Version", "3");

// Setze die erneuerten Metadaten
pdf.setXmpMetadata(meta);

// Schließe ausgefüllte pdf
pdf.close();
```

If someone has any idea how to fix this, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are editing your metadata. Where did you get the idea to do that, and why do you need it ? I'm pretty sure that commenting out `pdf.setXmpMetadata(meta);` will unbreak the file.

Comment: Unfortunetely I do have to edit the metadata. The section I posted above with the ftx:ControlData is part of the metadata and has to be correct. I will try letting that out though, just to confirm that the problem lies indeed in the editing of the metadata.

Comment: Surprisingly commenting that line out did not change the outcome. Verapdf still shows the error. I verified that the metadata has not been changed by my program.

Comment: I can't really investigate further without the source document. If you are a customer of iText, then you can send it to us through our JIRA instance; otherwise, you'll need to find a way to publish the file (if this is allowed).

Comment: Can you tell me which version of iText you ran this example with ? It looks to me like the bug you mentioned was fixed in 7.1.0 at the latest.

Comment: I am running on 7.0.7.
I'll try upgrading to the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to blagae, my problem was solved. It was indeed the old version that was acting up.

Upgrading to the newest version fixed my issue.